# Get brand name, instead of ID - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Good someone can help me, I am not doing it well. I have a table called products, in it a field called `brand_id`, then I have a table called brands, in which I list it by its `ID` field, this table also contains a column called nombre.

**Model producto**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';

    public function marcas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Marca::class , 'id');
    }
}
```

**Model Marca**

class Marca extends Model

```
{
    protected $table = 'marcas';

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class , 'id_brand');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

public $categorias, $productos, $ofertados;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->productos = Producto::with('marcas')
                ->latest('id')
                ->limit(6)
                ->whereEstado(1)
                ->get();            
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)    
   <div class="col-4 catProduct">
      <div class="col-12 bordeCajon">
          @if ($pro->novedad == 1)
             <div class="nEntrada">NOVEDAD</div> 
          @endif

          @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
          @else
            <div class="oferta">OFERTA!</div>
          @endif   
          <div class="minHei">
             <img src="{{ asset("{$pro->imagen}") }}" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="paddingProducto">
             @php
                /** echo "<pre>"; print_r($pro->marcas);*/
             @endphp

             <h2> {{ $pro->marcas->mombre }} </h2>
             <h3>{{ $pro->producto }}</h3>
             <div class="dividerProd"></div>
             <h4>{{ $pro->pvpAhora }} <span>€</span></h4>

             @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
             @else
             <div class="pvpAntes">{{ $pro->pvpAntes }} <span>€</span></div>
              @endif 
             <a href="{{ route('web.detalle', ['cat' => $pro->categoria, 'sub' => $pro->subcategoria, 'url' => $pro->url]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btnForm pull-right">VER PRODUCTO</a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

**Error**

```
Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/camasLiteras/resources/views/index.blade.php
```

For example, in the marks table I have 4 marks. In the beginning I have 6 products each with a brand. Well it does what we have done is take the product and put the name of the brand in the same order of the brand table, that is, it does not put the name that it touches. And since there are 6 products but only 4 brands, that's why it says the 'name' of no-object '. If I deactivate two products it doesn't give me an error but it shows in each product a different brand, putting the 4 there are.

Comment: `$product->marcas` can return `null`

Comment: Please explain me better, I am Spanish but StackOverflow Spain does not know how to solve it, I do not speak English well @lagbox

Comment: What if you do this `<h2> {{ optional($pro->marcas)->nombre }} </h2>` what happens?

Comment: I have tried what you tell me, and it gives me the name of the brands. But in the wrong way. Right now I have 3 products and 2 brands, so it only prints two brands, it is as if the brands id is related to the product id @lewis4u

Comment: Well I don't know what exactly you expect to get but this optional() function simply returns the whole expression as null if $pro->marcas is null. If you know what I mean.
I thought that not all of the $pro objects have some value fro 'marcas'

Comment: All objects have a mark, some objects can have the same mark. In the end it is simple, I want to get the products and instead of getting the id_bran extract the name of the brand that is in the brands table. @lewis4u

Comment: Well, apparently one of them is `null` and that's why you get an error message... You will have to investigate that....

Comment: Any advice on how to investigate this, I have yesterday with the same and I do not see any error. But the most curious thing is that in the two that if it puts the mark, it does not put the marks that are, it is as if it only extracts the two marks that there are and puts them in order @lewis4u

Comment: I would start with `{{ dd($productos->pluck('marcas')) }}` and see if any of them is null

Comment: What you are considering is the brand id, rather than making the relationship between id_brand and id. Therefore, since there is no id 3 in the brands table, in product 3 it does not enter a brand. @lewis4u

Comment: Following my previous comment, if I created a third product, I would get a category name. that's why it doesn't get the value as it plays and that's why it didn't work